# How to remove character "T" in a DateTimeField in Django Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I have a list with comments, those comments have a moment field, which is a DateTimeField. In this DateTimeField I have for example this --> 2020-06-03T15:32:01.803027 and I want to delete that T character, or replace with a blank space.

I'm using Django for the backend and Vue.js for the frontend.
I was able to remove the Z character by changing the USE_TZ = True to False option in the settings.py file. But I can't remove the T character, that's all I need. I have tried from the frontend to remove the T character using methods and computed properties, but I can't use the replace("T", " ") method on a DateTimeField, I can only use it on a String

```html
<template lang="html">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col text-left">
               <h2>Detalles del partido</h2>
           </div>
       </div>

        <div class="row">
           <div class="col">
               <div class="card">
                   <div class="card-body">

                       <form>
                        <form @submit="onSubmit">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombreLocal" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Local</label>    
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <input type="text" name="nombreLocal" class="form-control" readonly v-model.trim="form.nombreLocal">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombreVisitante" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Visitante</label>    
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <input type="text" name="nombreVisitante" class="form-control" readonly v-model.trim="form.nombreVisitante">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="resultado" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Resultado</label>    
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <input type="text" name="resultado" class="form-control" readonly v-model.trim="form.resultado">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="pronosticoSistema" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Pronóstico del sistema</label>    
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <input type="text" name="pronosticoSistema" class="form-control" readonly v-model.trim="form.pronosticoSistema">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="premio" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Premio</label>    
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <input type="number" name="premio" class="form-control" readonly v-model.trim="form.premio">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="dificultad" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dificultad</label>    
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <input type="text" name="dificultad" class="form-control" readonly v-model.trim="form.dificultad">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="rows">
                            <div class="col text-left">
                            <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" :to="{ name:'CreatePronostico', params: {partidoId: this.partidoId} }">
                            Pronosticar
                            </b-button>    
                            <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" :to="{ name:'CreateComentario', params: {partidoId: this.partidoId}}">
                            Comentar
                            </b-button>
                            <b-button size="sm" type="submit" class="btn-large-space" :to="{ name: 'PronosticadorUsuario'}">Atrás</b-button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </form>
                        <br>
                        <h2>Comentarios</h2>
                        <br>
                        <div class="comentarios">
                            <b-table striped hover 
                                :items="comentarios" 
                                :fields="fields"
                                :sort-by.sync="sortBy" 
                                :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc">
                                <template v-slot:cell(action)="data">
                                    <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" :to="{ name:'CreateComentarioRespuesta', params: {comentarioId: data.item.id} }">
                                        Responder
                                    </b-button>
                                    <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" :to="{ name:'DarMeGusta', params: {comentarioId: data.item.id} }">
                                        Me gusta
                                    </b-button>
                                    <b-button size="sm" variant="primary" :to="{ name:'EditComentario', params: {comentarioId: data.item.id} }">
                                        Editar
                                    </b-button>
                                    <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" :to="{ name:'DeleteComentario', params: {comentarioId: data.item.id} }">
                                        Eliminar
                                    </b-button>
                                </template>
                            </b-table>
                        </div>  


                       </form> 
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>       
    </div>  
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import swal from 'sweetalert'
import router from "../../router";

export default {

    mounted() {
        this.checkLoggedIn();
    },

    data() {
        return {
            sortBy: 'momento',
            sortDesc: false,
            partidoId: this.$route.params.partidoId,
            form: {
                nombreLocal: '',
                nombreVisitante: '',
                resultado: '',
                pronosticoSistema: '',
                premio: '',
                dificultad: ''
            },
        
            fields: [
                { key: 'id', label: 'Número de comentario' },
                { key: 'momento', label: 'Momento', sortable: true},
                { key: 'texto', label: 'Texto' },
                { key: 'meGustas', label: 'Número de "me gustas"', sortable: true},
                { key: 'autor', label: 'Autor' },
                { key: 'comentarioRespuesta', label: 'Responde a' },
                { key: 'action', label: '' }
            ],
            comentarios: []
        }
    },
    methods: {

        checkLoggedIn() {
         this.$session.start();
        if (!this.$session.has("token")) {
            router.push("/auth");
            }
        },

        onSubmit(evt){
            evt.preventDefault()

            const path = `http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/partidos/${this.partidoId}/`

            axios.get(path, this.form).then((response) =>{

                this.form.nombreLocal = response.data.nombreLocal
                this.form.nombreVisitante = response.data.nombreVisitante
                this.form.resultado = response.data.resultado
                this.form.pronosticoSistema = response.data.pronosticoSistema
                this.form.premio = response.data.premio
                this.form.dificultad = response.data.dificultad

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })

        },

        getPartido (){
            const path = `http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/partidos/${this.partidoId}/`

            axios.get(path).then((response) =>{

                this.form.nombreLocal = response.data.nombreLocal
                this.form.nombreVisitante = response.data.nombreVisitante
                this.form.resultado = response.data.resultado
                this.form.pronosticoSistema = response.data.pronosticoSistema
                this.form.premio = response.data.premio
                this.form.dificultad = response.data.dificultad

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        },

    getComentarios (){

      const path = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/comentarios/'
      axios.get(path).then((response) => {
        this.comentarios = response.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },

},

    computed: {
      comentariosFormateados: function (){
          var res = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < this.comentarios.length; i++){
              this.comentarios[i].momento.toISOString().replace('T', '');
              res.push(comentarios[i]);
          }
        return res;
      }

    },

    created() {
        this.getPartido(),
        this.getComentarios()
    }
}
</script>>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: where is the DateTimeField?

Comment: Can't you just use this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date ?

Comment: The DateTimeField is in the backend, I'm going to put it, to show you

Comment: @MeL I have tried to use this, but I don't know exactly how to use it and where to use it, can you give me an example or something?

Comment: Can you show your models.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with this:

`formatMomento(value) { const formattedDate = DateTime.fromISO(value).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT); return formattedDate; },`

And calling it from the formatter attribute:

```
fields: [
            { key: 'id', label: 'Número de comentario' },
            { key: 'momento', formatter: "formatMomento", label: 'Momento', sortable: true},
            { key: 'texto', label: 'Texto' },
            { key: 'meGustas', label: 'Número de "me gustas"', sortable: true},
            { key: 'autor', formatter: "nombreDeUsuario", label: 'Autor' },
            { key: 'comentarioRespuesta', label: 'Responde al comentario:' },
            { key: 'action', label: '' }
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the Django DateTime object formatted however you want, for example:

```
myDateTime = strftime(MyModel.objects.get(id=id).moment, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Or:

```
comment = MyModel.objects.get(id=id)
moment = strftime(comment.moment, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
comment.formatted_moment = moment
...
```

Then return it to your view in that format (a formatted string).